# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_grade'

Tags: python, class, oop

hello was following alone in a tutorial and the code that he has is the exact same that i have here but mine doesn't seem to work. when he ran the code his worked completely fine and i am running into errors. code it be that i need to add the parent to the subject such as subject(person)? or is something just wrong. The number get_average function should just return the number but it is having problems with that. appreciate the help

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, first, last, grade):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.grade = grade

    def get_grade(self):
        return self.grade

class Subject():
    def __init__(self, subject, number_students):
        self.subject = subject
        self.number_students = number_students
        self.students = []


    def add(self, name):
        if len(self.students) < self.number_students:
            self.students.append(name)
            return True
        return False

    def average(self):
        number = 0
        for i in self.students:
            number += i.get_grade()

        return number


p1 = Person("dustin", "white", 83)
subs = Subject("science", 10)
subs.add(p1.first)
print(subs.students)
print(subs.average())
```

Comment: p1.first is a string, so calling get_grade on it is not possible. It's hard to tell but I'm assuming you need to append the instance of your Person class to the students list. so you would do ```subs.add(p1)```. Then you would be able to call the methods of your Person class on it.

Comment: You should use `subs.add(p1)` so that the entire student is added to the list of students, and not just the first name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error arises because you run `subs.add(p1.first)`, which is a `type str`. `p1.first` does not have the method `get_grade`. What you want to run is: `subs.add(p1)` (the object which will have `get_grade`). Also, you can remove the redundant parentheses when defining the classes. You can write `class Subject():` as `class Subject:`.

You can then change you `add` code to:

```
def add(self, student):
    if len(self.students) < self.number_students:
        self.students.append(student.first) # changed here
        return True
    return False
```